# Python определить порт ssl

Tags: python, ssl

День добрый, возник такой вопрос. Как средствами Python определить порт, на котором стоит ssl, ибо не всегда это бывает 443.

Comment: Определить на локальной машине или на удалённой?

Comment: Определить на любом ресурсе. К примеру на сайте каком-нибудь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос "как сделать это в python" давайте вначале рассмотрим вопрос "как это сделать вне python"

Согласно [rfc 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) стандартный порт HTTP/TLS (ssl) - 443. Всё, что ему не соответствует считается настройкой непубличных сетей. То есть если вы нашли сервис, у которого ssl настроен на другом порту, то вероятнее всего это сервис для каких-то непубличных целей.

Кстати многие публичные сети закрывают все порты, кроме 80 и 443.

Рассмотрим как всё-таки понять открыт порт или нет. Для этого существует программа nmap (также со всякими графическими оболочками, вроде zenmap), которая может сканировать порты на удалённой машине. Пример:

```
# nmap -A -T4 -F www.microsoft.com

Starting Nmap ( http://nmap.org )
Nmap scan report for 80.67.68.30
(The 1208 ports scanned but not shown below are in state: closed)
PORT    STATE    SERVICE     VERSION
22/tcp  open     ssh         Akamai-I SSH (protocol 1.5)
80/tcp  open     http        AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration service)
443/tcp open     ssl/http    AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration service)
```

Также подобное можно реализовать в python через сокеты:

```
for port in range(1,1025):  
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))
    if result == 0:
        print "Port {} is open".format(port)
    sock.close()
```

Вот [тут есть пример](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/port-scanner-in-python)

Ну а дальше вам остаётся только разобраться что из этого ssl. В rfc написано, что необходимо отправить handshake и ждать ответа.

Мне случаи нестандартных ssl портов не встречались, однако при перенаправлении с http версии сервер должен указать на какой он порт перенаправляет (обычно порт опускается, должно быть что-то вроде https://example.ru:888/, например). Можно запросить при помощи любой библиотеки (urllib, requests) и посмотреть куда идёт редирект. Все они умеют отображать порт адреса